# IntelliJ can't find inverse attribute in many-to-many relationship when the inverse attribute has final keywords

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

Let's suppose we have two entities in many-to-many bi-directional relationships, `Student` and `Subject`.

```java
@Getter
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Setter
    private String name;

    @JoinTable(
            name = "student_subject",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id")
    )
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private final Set<Subject> subjects = new LinkedHashSet<>();

// constructors and etc.
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Entity
public class Subject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Setter
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "subjects")
    private final Set<Student> students = new LinkedHashSet<>();

// constructors and etc.
}
```

Each collection field is set to `final` and has no setter. This is intentional design to prevent it from being accidentally re-initialized to other collection instance after the persistence context takes care of it.

You can test if the entities above are working using this simple repository interface:

```java
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {}
```

and the following test works:

```java
@Test
void studentMattStudiesMathAndHistory() {
    Student student = new Student("Matt");
    student.getSubjects().add(new Subject("Math"));
    student.getSubjects().add(new Subject("History"));
    studentRepository.saveAndFlush(student);
}
```

So it looks like there's no trouble in entity design. However, IntelliJ seems to have different thought about this.

[image]

IntelliJ tells me that it `can't find inverse attribute`, in this case it's `subjects` field and is obviously existent right inside the `Student`. Well I figured out how to fix this red underline. Just remove `final` keyword like this:

```java
private Set<Subject> subjects = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

and the red underline is gone. Of course there's still no setter for it, so IntelliJ tells me to put the `final` keyword back for the code suggestion.

[image]

So the question is, why IntelliJ is not able to find the inverse attribute `subjects`? Is it a bug, or am I missing something?

#### Version spec.

- Spring Boot: `2.7.2`
- IntelliJ: `2022.2`

Comment: also confirmed in IntelliJ `2022.2.1`

Comment: You shouldn't make fields `final` when using libraries that instantiate instances, eg hibernate, jackson, et al. If you want to not have a setter, remove @Setter from the class and annotate only the settable fields with @Setter

Answer (score 2):

As per JPA documentation '**No methods or persistent instance variables must be declared final**'. remove final keyword from variable.

for details [check](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqb/index.html)

Comment: So it's a spec. Thx for the reference. Still curious why `final` keyword actually made no trouble though.